# Converting Parse GeoPoint into a CLLocation in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am working in Swift.

In my Parse backend I have a key called locations which has a number of geoPoint values of which are latitude and longitude points. I want to query/fetch all these points and place them into an array so I can then use them as different annotations on a map.

I am having trouble querying the locations so that they can be used as a CLLocation for the map.

If anyone could help me do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What code are you using to perform the query? And what do you mean by "I am having trouble querying the locations"? What sort of trouble?

Comment: I am using the code: var query = PFUser.query() and then query.whereKey. I am not sure how to query the Locations from parse and then convert them into a CLLocation so they can be used as annotations on a map.

Comment: Are you trying to query and find locations in the DB that are near a certain location?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to query and find locations closest the the current user, then place them place as annotations on a map. I know how to query users from Parse. and I know how to place annotations on a map. It's just doing it all together I am struggling with. Any help I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a variable as a PFGeoPoint and you can put your data from parse into this variable:

```
var descLocation: PFGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint()

var innerP1 = NSPredicate(format: "ObjectID = %@", objectID)
    var innerQ1:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Test", predicate: innerP1)

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([innerQ1])
    query.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                descLocation = object["GeoPoint"] as PFGeoPoint
            }
        } else {
            println("Error")
        }

    }
```

And in your class where you need the location, just add these line:

```
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = descLocation.latitude
    var longtitude: CLLocationDegrees = descLocation.longitude

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longtitude)
```

So you can add annotation to your map using this code:

```
    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = "Test"
    annotation.coordinate = location
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```